# non-negative definite function definition

Tags: discrete-mathematics, functions, probability-distributions

In one of my courses there is a definition that says:

A function $K$ taking values on integers is a nonnegative function if and only if

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n} a_i K(i-j) a_j \geq 0,\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}_+,\space\forall a=(a_1, ..., a_n)^T \in \mathbb{R}^n.$$

This confuses me quite a bit.

In my mind a nonnegative function is a function that does not attain negative values, i.e. it can have positive or zero values for output.

So I could have $K(-1)=1,\space K(0)=0,\space K(1)=1$, (So K is nonnegative), and $a=(1,-1)$.

This would give $[1\times0\times1] + [(-1)\times0 \times (-1)] + 2 [1\times1\times (-1)]=-2$.

Another example would be $K(-2)=1,\space K(-1)=1,\space K(0)=0,\space K(1)=1,\space K(2)=1$ and $a=(-1,1,-1)$, which would give $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n} a_i K(i-j) a_j = -4$ (if I'm not mistaken).

So I don't quite understand why this definition is used to define nonnegative functions, or the notion of nonnegative functions (as I have been told in the comments).

Comment: The "Theorem" you refer to is actually the **definition** of the notion of nonnegative function, a concept which has nothing to do with pointwise nonnegative functions.

Comment: Ah now that you mention it, it is indeed a definition. I will edit that. Even as a definition it still quite confused though.

Comment: It is against convetions to call such a  fucntin non-negative. The correct term is **non-neagtive definite** function.

Comment: ok, thank you. Will update.